# Ping request timed out when basehttpserver is loading website

Tags: php, python, http-headers, basehttpserver

I am running a website using basehttpserver.

When loading a simple website, just a 22kb image file (locally hosted) - all ping request time out while this image / webpage is loading. When it's done, the ping becomes successful again.

The original website was far more complex, but I narrowed it down to it happening even with a simple website like this.

Can anyone offer any insight to why this might be happening? And if I should be worried about it?

I've looked into changing the php/http headers (with no luck), and hosting the website externally on an IIS server (it loads just fine, no ping issues) - so I know it's something to do with the basehttpserver... but other than that I'm a bit out of my depth. Many thanks.

PHP DOC (status.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="image22kb.jpg" style="width:640px; height:auto;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

PING CMD

[image]

HTTP HEADERS:

[image]

EDIT:

Sorry, not sure if this is helpful, but tracert times out on the final hop when website is loading.

[image]

Comment: your hosting locally?

Comment: The website is being hosted externally, and as accessed via an external, static IP address.

Comment: but 10.0 is in the private network range

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to all this. 10.0.xx.xx is the ip to access the site. There is a 'controller' with a cellular modem on it, which hosts the website and runs the basehttpserver.

Comment: i doubt that kind of hosting is very robust or reliable. I suggest taking this to: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Thanks, I will do. Unfortunately I am stick with the infrastructure as stated above. Appreciate the help.